How to use ajax to get data in Spring Authorization Server demo-client
When I use the demo-authorizationserver, messages-resource, and demo-client in the spring authorization server samples, I want to use ajax to get userlist in the demo-client. The demo-client reports an error。

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=8U7X77oupXyeCXBv-0jKyATz_H3UJxdjCxHGIjv8A80%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/list') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
GET http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=message.read%20message.write&state=8U7X77oupXyeCXBv-0jKyATz_H3UJxdjCxHGIjv8A80%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized net::ERR_FAILED

ajax:
function loadUserList1(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/user/list",
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      //  console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

}
I have not made any changes to demo-authorizationserver, message-resource, and demo-client. I want to use ajax to get data in demo-client. How should I do it?
